# Bootstrap, CSS and HTML: best way to change height for small and large screen with grid system?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap v3 's grid system. I my example (my real code is more complex) I want to have three columns in the same row, all columns should have the same height. Since the columns are side by side, I can set their `height`to 100%. However, on a small screen, they get stacked and then still fill 100% of the screen. How does one avoid this?

Is the best solution to include:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .small-vert-height{
      max-height:50px;
      height:auto;
  }
}
```

in my code or is there a more natural bootstrap way to achieve columns that fill their entire div and still stack well on small displays?

```css
html,body, .container-fluid{
 height:100%;
}

body{
 padding:15px;
 background-color:black;
}


.red-square{
 background-color: red;
 border-radius: 0;
}

.pink-square{
 background-color:#B90276;
 border-radius:0;
}

.green-square{
 background-color:#78BE20;
 border-radius:0;
 color:white;
 font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dummy_v2.css">
</head>


<body style="height:100%;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" style="height:100%">
 <div class="col-sm-1 pink-square" style="height:100%">
  <h1> ldsafldsaf ald l </h1>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-10 red-square" style="height:100%">
  <h1> ldsafldsaf ald l </h1>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-1 green-square" style="height:100%">
  <h1> ldsafldsaf ald l </h1>
 </div>
</div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, on small screens you want items to stack vertically and have combined height 100% of veiwport? Have you considered `vh` units for height?

Comment: I have not. could you maybe outline shortly what you would do with `vh`?

Answer (score 3):

I would consider a flexbox. You don't have to specify the height because all flex items automatically stretch.

```css
html,
body,
.container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: black;
}

.container-fluid .row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

.red-square {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}

.pink-square {
  background-color: #B90276;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  }

.green-square {
  background-color: #78BE20;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  }

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .small-vert-height {
    max-height: 50px;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1 pink-square">
      <h1> ldsafldsaf ald l asdf sdafds asdfdsf</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 red-square">
      <h1> ldsafldsaf ald l </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 green-square">
      <h1> ldsafldsaf ald l </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. However, in your code snippet the code does not stack anymore. I would like it to stack, but not to fill 100% of the screen height.

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap grid system has four classes: xs (phones), sm (tablets), md (desktops), and lg (larger desktops). The classes can be combined to create more dynamic and flexible layouts. Each class scales up, so if you wish to set the same widths for xs and sm, you only need to specify xs.
Example

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-lg-8">.col-xs-7 .col-sm-6 .col-lg-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">.col-xs-5 .col-sm-6 .col-lg-4</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8 col-lg-10">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-8 .col-lg-10</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4 .col-lg-2</div>
</div>
```